# 8085 Programming Basics

Tags: microprocessor, assembly, 8085, assembler

[image]

Bcz of CALL, SP will be decremented by 2. Then bcz of POP, SP will get incremented by 2. So, SP will be 27FFH. But, I am confused with HL register part. Please help me with the above problem.

Comment: Please tell me why you downvoted the question.

Comment: What is your confusion? Look up what 'pop h' (actually 'pop hl') does.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen How will the stack look? (1004->10H,1005->06H ) is it correct? So, HL = 0610H ?

Comment: I don't know the details, but that should be it (give or take a swap of those values, and check whether the saved PC is really the instruction to return to or one less).

Comment: PS Why are we regularly getting questions about 8085 assembly and not about other stone-age micro-processors? Has someone in some Indian university found a truckload of 8085 development boards? IMO nowaydays Intel (for PC) and Cortex-M (for embedded) would be more relevant.

Comment: I am EEE graduate. Mostly engineers prepare for GATE (Graduate Aptitude Test in Engg) which offers high paying govt jobs and Mtech opportunities. Its syllabus has not been revised for last 20 yrs.

Comment: Lol ya. Despite we have lotta brilliant brains in India, it is sad that our syllabus still holds on to primitive stuffs still. After all what is the useof remembering how many bytes is a CALL instruction in 8085. I had to google.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen, the oldies are simpler to see the principles in for your  first steps in microprocessors. It's good to see what life's like without the modern CPU features so you can understand why they're put in. There's a similar argument for teaching the 741 op-amp and so on - the pros and cons and shortfalls are very apparent. Only for a month or so though and then on to modern CPUs, hopefully to God :-)

Comment: @TonyM sure the oldies were more understandable, but I was wondering why all such questions are about 8085. No 8080, 6500, 6800, Z80, 1802, SC/MP. But "Its syllabus has not been revised for last 20 yrs." explains it all. Now I'll go back to the impact of C++17 on my embedded courses :)

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen I recently graduated college as well. They had us take a microprocessors class and we learned about the old 8-bit Motorola 68HC11. I don't know why they still teach us this stuff. However, I took a class in computer architecture that utilized MIPS Assembly. I think what they want to do with old technology is talk about very basic addressing in a chip.

Comment: You've got a fair question there, @WoutervanOoijen :-) I've seen the 8086 come up a lot here, too. I know there's some thriving Z80, 6502 and 68k forums so maybe they mop up questions on those CPUs. For a capable CPU with a bit of everything that introduces ideas that need improving, I'd have gone for the Z80. The 8080, 8085 and 8086 never seemed to inspire the same interest and nostalgia.

Answer (score 1):

- SP Points to address 27FF
- CALL occurs at 1003, So PC's current value is stored on to stack. CALL is a 3 byte instruction, means PC points to -> 1003+3 = 1006. It is stored on to Stack (decrement and store).

  27FE <- 06, 27FD <- 10 and SP now points to the top, 27FD.
- Program control is taken to 1006 by CALL.
- POP H will Pop values from the Stack to HL reg pair(pop and increment).

  H <- 10 , L <- 06. SP will point to 27FF.